# NoClassDefFoundError: Not able to invoke chromedriver

Tags: noclassdeffounderror, selenium-java

[Workspace trying to invoke the chromedriver using selenium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTlDp.png
->Java-jdk:17
->Selenium-java-4.12.1
->Chromedriver extracted from the latest version of mine 119versions through Chrome for testing availability of stable Channel.

->I have add selenium-java "JAR'S" To module path through build path of the project not to the class path .I have tried in class path but in the class path i was not able to use the ChromeDriver by importing org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver so i removed the JAR's from the class path and added those JAR's to the module path then i was able to import those package.

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/io/ByteStreams at org.seleniumhq.selenium.remote_driver/org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.parseLogOutput(DriverService.java:468) at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.loadSystemProperties(ChromeDriverService.java:291) at org.seleniumhq.selenium.remote_driver/org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:491) at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:157) at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:51) at Automation/Auto.ToLaunchApplicaton.main(ToLaunchApplicaton.java:9) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.io.ByteStreams at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ... 6 more`
I got this error message while runnning the code .after all the setup i have done to invoke chromedriver.
the code is:

```
package Auto;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class ToLaunchApplicaton {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Automation\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    }

}
```

I am expecting to invoke chrome browser for my software testing process